# Как правильно сделать override функции ядра Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

Нужно поправить функцию, которая находится в компоненте `/bitrix/components/bitrix/system.field.edit`.

1. Перенес данный компонент в свое пространство имен:
   `/bitrix/components/my_name_space/intranet.user.search`,
   и тут поправил необходимую мне функцию.
2. Нашел компонент, где вызывается этот компонент и исправил нэймспейс на свой.
   Но тот компонент также в ядре находится. Теперь что, переносить этот к себе и искать, где вызывается он? ))

Вот и дилемма, искать всю цепочку, или есть более простой способ?

Или я что-то не понимаю? Спасибо.

Comment: Может попробовать относледоваться от них? Что за компоненты хоть?

Comment: а что мешает подключить переделанный компонент?

Comment: Какое действие вызывает функцию?  Может стоит не наследовать компонент а создать обработчик на свое новое  событие (EventHandler)?

Comment: @THE3X1LE Это в процессе постановки задачи (Битрикс 24) при выборе ответственного, открывается окно с пользователями. Вот когда выбираешь нужного и нажимаешь Открыть, происходит это событие. Как понять, можно ли на него прицепиться?

Comment: @Сергей если бы вы прочитали про обработчики событий, то у Вас бы не было такого вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

> Нашел компонент, где вызывается этот компонент и исправил нэймспейс на свой. Но тот компонент также в ядре находится. Теперь что, переносить этот к себе и искать, где вызывается он? ))

он ведь вызывается в шаблоне, скопируйте себе этот шаблон и замените вызов на свой кастомизированый компонент.

вообще копирование самих компонентов это крайняя мера, уверены что Вашу задачу нельзя решить копированием шаблона и внесением правок в result_modifier или component_epilog?